# cards not displaying fully on the screen

Tags: android, android-cardview, display

On my Screen i have some cards to show but they are not fitting in to whole screen

This is my xml for `CardView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:orientation="vertical"

>




<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"


    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cardview_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"


        >

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@color/colorGray">

        </View>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

                android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/university"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGray"


                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="14dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/city"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGray"


                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>




        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>




</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


 </LinearLayout>
```

[image: final image]

Here is my home.xml in which i implemented recyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.raheel.bank.Home"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:scrollbars="vertical"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to display the cards fully on the screen in order to look more clearly and easy to use.As it is not fitting into the activity right now.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` property to cardview. Hope it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the xml is used as an item for `ListView` or `RecyclerView` make sure the `RecyclerView` is not having any margin.

Comment: much better after removing padding from recyclerView. But not as good as i wonder it to be .

Comment: remove the padding values from relative layout